# Linq groupby and sum

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Basically I have a class with two proprties - `ParentProduct` and `NumberOfOrders`.  I want to select the distinct parent product, ordered by the total number of orders so I used the following Linq:

```
var list = List.GroupBy(t => t.ParentProduct)
               .Select(group => new { Product = group.Key, NumberOfOrders = group.Sum(t => t.NumberOfOrders) })
               .OrderBy(o => o.NumberOfOrders)
                     .Select(o => o.Product);
```

Where `List` is a list of all child products
 
`t` is the child product that contains the number of orders and the parent product
`o` is the new object created

I was wondering if there was a better way to get a distinct list of parent products that is ordered by the sum of orders as the above seems to be doing a lot of selects.

Comment: It seems to me the better way.

Comment: I don't understand your `data structure` well, you want to **select distinct parent**, so what if you have 2 entries of the same `ParentProduct` with different `NumberOfOrders`, which one you choose between them to calculate the `sum of NumberOfOrders`?

Comment: @KingKing because I am grouping by parents, that should handle the distinct part of it, I was just wondering if I could get a list of just parents ordered by the sum of the number of orders (but without the NumberOfOrders) without having to do 2 selects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove the middle select and just order the groups by the sums and then select the product.

```
var list = List.GroupBy(t => t.ParentProduct)
               .OrderBy(group => group.Sum(t => t.NumberOfOrders))
               .Select(group => group.Key);
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was after. Thanks!